# Перевод описания сообщества "Русский язык"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

> For лингвистов, этимологов, и энтузиастов русского языка

[image: ошибка перевода]

Перевод в выпадающем меню описания сообщества начинается с английского слова `For...` вместо `Для...`

Comment: Возможно, этому больше место [у них на Мете](http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Локализация, полагаю, общая

Comment: @D-side там у них переводчиков - полторы калеки. Лучше мы поправим.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ага. Поправим. Конечно.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, на данный момент исправить перевод технически невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Большинство из "ветеранов" давно забыли, как выглядит сайт для новичка. Во всех всплывающих подсказках - сплошной "инглиш".
- Непорядок это. Разумеется нужно добиваться от "платформы" уважительного к себе отношения. Даже машинный перевод - и тот вызовет больше положительных эмоций, нежели их "усиленно навязываемый" инглиш.
*Цитирую всплывающую подсказку:*

> Thanks for contributing an answer to Русский язык! Please be sure to
>   answer the question. Provide details and share your research! But
>   avoid … Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other
>   answers. Making statements based on opinion; back them up with
>   references or personal experience. To learn more, see our tips on
>   writing great answers.